# Sphinx + Group By returns "index rt: group-by attribute not found"

Tags: indexing, group-by, sphinx, faceted-search, rt

I'm trying to build a search engine for my site using the latest version 2.0.4 of sphinx. Indexing and sending queries works so far. But I also want to display some facets so I'll do the same query twice. The first for the normal search results and the second by grouping for a certain attribute. My sphinx.conf looks like this:

```
{
    ...

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT aID AS id, aFullname AS text, 'artist' AS type \
        FROM artist

    sql_attr_string     = type

    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM artist WHERE aID=$id
}


source src2
{
    ...

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT album_id AS id, album_name AS text, 'album' AS type \
        FROM albums

    sql_attr_string     = type

    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM albums WHERE album_id=$id
}


index rt
{
    type              = rt
    path              = /var/data/rt

    rt_field          = text

        rt_attr_uint      = id
    rt_attr_string    = type
}
```

But when I'm using the second query with

```
$cl->SetGroupBy('type', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, '@count desc' );
```

I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: index rt: group-by attribute 'type' not found
```

Can anyone spot an error in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

At a total guess

```
rt_attr_uint      = id
```

looks odd. Not sure you can have a custom attribute called id. Its the name of the document_id - which is handled specially. Try renaming that.